# Tell OpenLdap to use already encrypted pw

Tags: openldap, password-encryption, phpldapadmin

I'm new to Ldap and try to import all my User.

I try to add a Person like this:

```
dn: cn=Thomas Bendler,ou=Development,o=selflinux,dc=selflinux,dc=de
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalperson
objectclass: inetorgperson
cn: Thomas Bendler
sn: Bendler
ou: Development
mail:project@selflinux.de
userpassword: {CRYPT}saHW9GdxihkGQ
```

But I have a Problem with     userpassword: {CRYPT}saHW9GdxihkGQ

My Database already contains encrypted Passwords like this a913759b1331c15d3048b7142fb75e50

How can I tell OpenLdap/phpldapadmin to use the encrypted form and not to encrypt it again?

Answer (score 0):

As for the [documentation of OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html), the password does not need to be stored encrypted and/or hashed.

So if you want to store an already encrypted/hashed password, it needs to be compliant with the authentication mechanism of OpenLDAP, which schemes are for example : SSHA, CRYPT, MD5, SMD5, SHA, etc.

If the password you have in your database are not crypted by a mechanism known by openldap you won't be able to import them like that.

Comment: thanks. It looks like it was a Problem with MD5 Hash Generation on the Server. 
If I generated the Value it was different from the one from Server. Now i switched to Apacheds and SHA512. But thanks for the answere